# Source for learning etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, online-resources

I want to understand the concepts of etale cohomology and I have absolutely no background on homological algebra. I have a basic understanding about algebraic geometry. Can anyone suggest me a source to learn this? Any course notes or video lectures will be helpful.

Comment: Weibel's book on homological algebra is excellent. See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80633/textbook-for-etale-cohomology).

Comment: Just to supplement @DietrichBurde 's response, Weibel will give you a good background in homological algebra, but it doesn't actually discuss etale cohomology (as far as I can tell anyway).

Comment: The books "From calculus to cohomology: de Rham cohomology and characteristic classes" (Cambridge, see https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/From-Calculus-to-Cohomology%3A-De-Rham-Cohomology-and-Madsen-Tornehave/d7435f220a4976a275098a1e16f6d55a232fc43a) and "Galois Cohomology and Class Field Theory" (Springer, see https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030439002) seem to be a good source.

Comment: One standard reference for etale cohomology is the book by Milne.

Comment: Yes, Milne's text is several times mentioned at the [duplicate](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80633/textbook-for-etale-cohomology).